# Should I use a seperate beans.xml configuration for instantiating objects in my unit tests?

Tags: spring, unit-testing, instantiation

Here's my Beans.xml for my application

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">


        <bean id="myRoom" class="org.world.hello.Room">
            <property name="bottleCounter">
                <bean id="myBottleCounter" class="org.world.hello.BottleCounter" />
            </property>
            <property name="numBottles" value="10"></property>

        </bean>    
</beans>
```

It's one `Room` bean that has a `BottleCounter` bean as a property.

Now, I want to write a unit testing for `BottleCounter`.

```
public class BottleCounterTest {

    ApplicationContext context; 

    @Before
    public void setUp()
    {
        context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");      
    }

    @Test
    public void testOneBottle() {

        BottleCounter bottleCounter = (BottleCounter) context.getBean("myBottleCounter");

        assertEquals("1 bottles of beer on the wall1 bottles of beer!", bottleCounter.countBottle(1));
    }

}
```

But I can't directly reference `myBottleCounter` as it's a inner bean? And gives me `No bean named 'myBottleCounter' is defined`.

So should instead, I be defining my test beans in a seperate xml?

eg.

**testBeans.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">


        <bean id="testRoom" class="org.world.hello.Room">
            <property name="bottleCounter">
                <bean id="myBottleCounter" class="org.world.hello.BottleCounter" />
            </property>
            <property name="numBottles" value="3"></property>

        </bean>

        <bean id="testBottleCounter" class="org.world.hello.BottleCounter" />



</beans>
```

**BottleCounterTest.java**

```
public class BottleCounterTest {

    ApplicationContext context; 

    @Before
    public void setUp()
    {
        context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("testBeans.xml");      
    }

    @Test
    public void testOneBottle() {

        BottleCounter bottleCounter = (BottleCounter) context.getBean("testBottleCounter");

        assertEquals("1 bottles of beer on the wall1 bottles of beer!", bottleCounter.countBottle(1));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
Room room = (Room) context.getBean("myRoom");
BottleCounter bottleCounter = room.getBottleCounter();
```

OR, if you can modify the XML file, then declare the `BottleCounter` bean separately.

```
<bean id="testRoom" class="org.world.hello.Room">
    <property name="bottleCounter">
        <ref bean="myBottleCounter"/>
    </property>
    <property name="numBottles" value="3"></property>

</bean>

<bean id="myBottleCounter" class="org.world.hello.BottleCounter" />
```

Comment: What I don't like about the first solution, is that the test requires knowing what the production structure is. Our test just wants to test that BottleCounter is working correctly. It shouldn't need to know that a Room owns it.

Comment: The second solution is better, but see my criticism to the other answer given.

Comment: Yes, I have seen your comments on the first solution, hence I recommended the second solution.

Comment: I mean my comment on Manish's answer.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way to do this would be:

```
<bean id="myBottleCounter" class="org.world.hello.BottleCounter" />

<bean id="testRoom" class="org.world.hello.Room">
  <property name="bottleCounter">
    <ref bean="myBottleCounter"/>
  </property>
  <property name="numBottles" value="3"></property>
</bean>

@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:Beans.xml")
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class BottleCounterTest {
  @Autowired
  BottleCounter bottleCounter;

  @Test
  public void testOneBottle() {
    assertEquals("1 bottles of beer on the wall1 bottles of beer!", bottleCounter.countBottle(1));
  }
}
```

To summarize, you declare an instance of the bean `BottleCounter` explicitly and then inject it into your test class using Spring.

**Make sure that `spring-test.jar` is on the classpath when the tests are run.**

Comment: What I don't like about this solution, is that it makes it hard to see the contents/relationship of the inner and outer beans. What you had 10 different Rooms, all with different BottleCounters? I think it's clear to define the inner beans inside the XML.

Comment: Then keep your inner beans and declare a separate one independently for testing.  If you are using Maven you can have a Spring application context initialization file in `src\test\resources` as well (for example, `TestBeans.xml`) and use this file for your tests.  The content of this file could be as simple as `<bean class="org.world.hello.BottleCounter" />`.  My point is that since Spring is already being used, it should be used for the test cases as well.